# Can AKKA be used where processing of events in order is important

Tags: akka

My project requires processing of the incoming events in the order they are received and no out of sequence happens.

Is this use case be addressed with AKKA.

Answer (score 1):

Messages as well as events are processed or pushed to an actor in the order the are received in the mailbox. See [Discussion: Message Ordering](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/general/message-delivery-reliability.html#Discussion__Message_Ordering)

> Actor A1 sends messages M1, M2, M3 to A2
>
> Actor A3 sends messages M4, M5, M6 to A2
>
> This means that:
>
> - M1 is delivered it must be delivered before M2 and M3
> - If M2 is delivered it must be delivered before M3
> - If M4 is delivered it must be delivered before M5 and M6
> - If M5 is delivered it must be delivered before M6
> - A2 can see messages from A1 interleaved with messages from A3
> - Since there is no guaranteed delivery, any of the messages may be dropped, i.e. not arrive at A2

It's possible to use `Stash` trait to allow message M2 be processed only when M1 has been processed independently of order they were sent to an actor. Thus insuring processing order. See more about [Stash](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/actors.html#Stash). An example below written in Scala.

```
class MyActor extends Actor with Stash {

    override def receive: Receive = receiveM1

    def receiveM1: Receive = {
        case M1 => 
            // do some staff with M1
            unstashAll()
            context become receiveM2
        case _ => 
            stash() 
    }

    def receiveM2: Receive = {
        case M2 => 
            // do some staff with M2
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, will look into Stash. Follow up questions:

Answer (score 0):

If tasks involved in the events are independent and it is required to improve performance, akka(or other asynchronous solutions) will address the problem. 
It is possible to process events asynchronously and aggregate the results in order.